# How can I make revision log message required based on revision checkbox by node_form_alter?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

My goal is to make the "**revision log message**" required if "**Create new revision**" is checked on create/edit node.

I do able to add the visible and required mark based on the "**create new revision**" field.

```
function hook_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['revision_information']['log']['#states'] = [
    'required' => [
      ':input[name="revision"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ],
    'visible'  => [
      ':input[name="revision"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ],
  ];
}
```

I also able to make the "**revision log message**" as required.

```
function hook_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['revision_information']['log']['#required'] = [
    'required' => [
      ':input[name="revision"]' => ['checked' => TRUE],
    ],
  ];
}
```

But I don't know how to make the field required based on the "**create new revision**" checkbox.

PS: I want to make this simple and don't want to use the ["Enforce revision log message](https://www.drupal.org/project/enforce_revlog)" module.

// update 1: I found it require a custom hook validate and Im searching for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer after hours of searching. Basically, I just need to add a custom hook validation for revision log. See below for my code.

```
function MYMODULENAME_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    // change revision log status based on revision checkbox
    $form['revision_information']['log']['#states'] = array(
        'required' => array(
          ':input[name="revision"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ),
        'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="revision"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ),
    );
}
function MYMODULENAME_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
    // add revision log validation
    if (empty($form_state['values']['log']) && ($form_state['values']['revision'])) {
        form_set_error('log', 'Revision log message cannot be empty!');
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone who needs revision log message required.

Comment: This is the great job, could you please tell me how this script paste into running drupal project? Create module or where should I place this src?

Comment: @Roman This is a hook function on a custom module. This code should be in the "module-name.module" file.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 and 9 i just do this sort of thing.

```
$form['revision_log']['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['revision_log']['widget']['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['revision_log']['widget'][0]['#required'] = TRUE;
$form['revision_log']['widget'][0]['value']['#required'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a simple module that does this.  Note, it will require the log message on any revision of a node, but not on initial creation.  Also, it currently affects all node types without regard to if the create new revision is clicked on the content type configuration.

https://www.drupal.org/project/require_revision_log_message/